# How to pass variable in component.html on page load Ajax request in Angular 11

Tags: angular, ajax, typescript, angular11

I have made a component and on html of that i want to have a variable, whose value is coming from ajax response in `ngOnInit`.

Problem is when i am trying to set the variable from object which is i am getting from ajax is give me `undefined`. May be ajax call is still running while it sets the variable. I want to ask how i can set the variable.

```
export class mainPage implements OnInit {
    public backgroundData: any;
    public backgroundImagePath : string = '';
  constructor(private $state: StateService, private MyService : MainServicesService) {
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getBackground();
      console.log(this.backgroundData);
      this.backgroundImagePath = environment.BaseUrl+this.backgroundData.folder+this.backgroundData.file;
  }

getBackground(){
      let client = this.client_id;
      this.MyService.getClientInfo(client)
          .subscribe(
              (data) => {
                  this.backgroundData  = data;

              } ,
              error => console.log(error)
          )
  }
```

I have also tried to put it in the constructor but no success.

Here is where i want to get the variable in html.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + backgroundImagePath + ')'}">
```

Comment: is `backgroundData` a public variable? Did you try setting a default value like '' for the `backgroundData` variable?

Comment: @MaartenDev Yes It is public variable let me update the question . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP call is indeed asynchronous and is not guaranteed to be finished when the next line is executed. An option would be to build the url when the request has finished:

```
export class mainPage implements OnInit {
    public backgroundData: any;
    public backgroundImagePath: string = '';

    constructor(private $state: StateService, private MyService: MainServicesService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadBackground();

    }

    loadBackground() {
        let client = this.client_id;
        this.MyService.getClientInfo(client)
            .subscribe(
                (backgroundData: any) => {
                    this.backgroundImagePath = environment.BaseUrl + backgroundData.folder + backgroundData.file;
                },
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Then it give me error for `Property 'folder' does not exist on type 'Object'. `and for file also same error.

Comment: It works with backgroundData:any . Thanks Solve my Problem. Let me test it thoroughly.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript work on asynchronous. Please replace

ngOnInit() with async ngOnInit()
this.getBackground() with await this.getBackground()

Comment: In this case he works with ```Observable``` not with ```Promise```.

Comment: @Vicky Kumar sorry did not understand your answer.